# How to automatically split table into subtables containing two consecutive rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have table like this:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | g |
| b | h |
| c | i |
| d | j |
| e | k |
| f | l |

I would like to automatically split table into subtables containing two consecutive rows, like below:

table1:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | g |
| b | h |

table2:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| b | h |
| c | i |

table3:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| c | i |
| d | j |

table4:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| d | j |
| e | k |

table5:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| e | k |
| f | l |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Iterate over dataframe and create variable dynamically with `locals`:

```
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    locals()[f"table{i+1}"] = df[i:i+2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> table1
  value1 value2
0      a      g
1      b      h

>>> table2
  value1 value2
0      b      h
1      c      i

...

>>> table5
  value1 value2
0      e      k
1      f      l
```

If you want the index remains across tableX remove `.reset_index(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting alternative is to use *as_strided* function from *Numpy* and
save the result as a list of DataFrames.

Start from the necessary import:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride
```

Then define the following function:

```
def decompose(df, rowNo):
    v = df.values
    d0, d1 = v.shape
    s0, s1 = v.strides
    a = stride(v, (d0 - (rowNo - 1), w, d1), (s0, s0, s1))
    return [ pd.DataFrame(a[i], columns=df.columns) for i in range(a.shape[0]) ]
```

When you call it:

```
result = decompose(df, 2)
```

the result is a list of DataFrames with particular fragments of the original
DataFrame.

E.g. `result[0]` contains:

```
  value1 value2
0      a      g
1      b      h
```

If you want to save each element of this list under a separate, elementary variable,
do it on your own.

Comment: unsure of the downote, good function imo.

Answer (score -1):

use a dictionary comprehension and a groupby, since you want consecutive rows, you can use floor division to create your groupby object.

```
tables = {f"table{x+1}" : y for x,y in df.groupby(df.index // 2) }


print(tables['table1'])

  value1 value2
0      a      g
1      b      h
```

---

```
tables.keys()
dict_keys(['table1', 'table2', 'table3'])
```